# Using form_set_error in the submit handler

Tags: forms

I have a multistep form and on each submit I send completed fields off to an external API which returns data about the next step of the form.

The problem is, if I use form_set_error in the submit handler, the form_storage is cleared and so the form resets to the first page.

Here's a arbitrary example;

```
function example_form($form, &$form_state) {
  if(!isset($form_state['step'])){
    $form_state['step'] = 1;
  }
  $form['test'] = array('#markup' => '<p>Step: ' . $form_state['step'] . '</p>');

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'go'
  );
  return $form;
}

function example_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  if($form_state['step'] > 5){
    form_set_error('test', 'error');
    return;
  }
  $form_state['step']++;
}
```

So this create a form with just a text block displaying the step number and a submit button that takes you to the next step. Until you go past the 5th step at which point it should start to error.

For some reason in my testing this breaks the step count, and on error takes you back to step 2.

moving the form_set_error into the form callback, or into a validate callback fixes the issue, but it would be cleaner if I could call it in the submit handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case it's useful to anyone else, I have a unsatisfactory work around;

Store the error in form_state, and look for them in the form callback.

```
function example_form($form, &$form_state) {
  // if we had an error in the submit handler, trigger it now
  if(isset($form_state['error']) && $form_state['error']){
    form_set_error('test', 'test');
  }
  if(!isset($form_state['step'])){
    $form_state['step'] = 1;
  }
  $form['test'] = array('#markup' => '<p>Step: ' . $form_state['step'] . '</p>');

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'go'
  );
  return $form;
}


function example_submit($form, &$form_state) {

  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  if($form_state['step'] > 5){
    //store error and return before the step is increased
    $form_state['error'] = true;
    return;
  }


  $form_state['step']++;
}
```

Comment: I would call that pretty satisfactory to be honest. `form_set_error()` is never supposed to be used in a submit handler (or a form function itself) so passing data back over the `$form_state` would definitely be the 'Drupal' way to handle this

Comment: Thanks Clive, that make me feel better about using it :)

Comment: This is great, it was very useful to me in a similar case, and I do think it's a pretty elegant way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

`form_set_error()` isn't supposed to be used in a submit handler; it's part of the validation workflow. From the docs:

> When a validation error is detected, the validator calls form_set_error() to indicate which element needs to be changed and provide an error message. **This causes the Form API to not execute the form submit handlers**, and instead to re-display the form to the user with the corresponding elements rendered with an 'error' CSS class (shown as red by default).

Emphasis mine.

The point is to use `form_set_error()` to stop the process from ever reaching the submit handler.

Don't forget, you're *validating* whether or not the current step is greater than 5. That logic needs to happen in a validation handler. :)

Comment: I understand that, but my problem is that it makes sense for this to happen in the submit handler. I have an API call that happens in the submit handler, if the API call fails, or returns an error, then I want to be able to set an error on the form and stay at the current step. I don't want to move the API call to a validation handler, because if successful the API call is a write action, so belongs at the submit stage. Also keeping it in the submit means other validators can prevent the API call from happening (eg honeypot).

Comment: No, because all validators will run. So if my API call is in a validator it will always run, even if honeypot is triggered. An error message will display but the data will still be send to the API and stored, defeating the point of honeypot.

Comment: Sorry yeah I read your comment too quickly. I'm not sure what to say I'm afraid; what you're doing is validation-specific logic and only makes sense to be in a validate handler to me. Look at the core image upload as an example - The expensive work (uploading and validating the file) is done in a validation handler, regardless of whether other validation handlers may run afterwards or not. Then the result of that validation is passed on to the submit handler. It mirrors your use-case quite closely

Comment: I agree validation makes sense in the validator, but this is more error handling than validation. Errors can  occur in the submit handler, and they are related to the form. I found one work around which is to store errors from the handler in form_storage, and then trigger the errors in the form callback. This works but seems a little messy. Its technically no different that triggering the error in submit handler, so it's frustrating that I would need to do it.

Comment: Not quite - error handling is the _response_ to an error that's been raised. The error has to come from somewhere, and in an HTML form workflow that place is the validation handler. Semantics though really. Drupal forces that workflow because it makes sense, if you can't use that process for whatever reason then yeah, you're going to be left with messy workarounds. You're going against the mould so-to-speak :)

Comment: It's just a catch 22 in my case, since the point of validators is to stop a write action occuring, moving my API call into the validator isn't feasible. Thanks for your help Clive.

Comment: No probs, glad you've got a way forward at least

Comment: You could make your validation handler run last and then do your API call in the validate function.

Comment: you can start to hit strange cases when trying to ensure your validation runs last. You need to alter the form and reshuffle the validation array as needed. What if another modules also wants/needs its validation to run last? It gets messy very quickly.

Comment: @Simon You could always implement `hook_module_implements_order()` to guarantee your own module's hooks will run last, but yeah it can get pretty messy like you say

Answer (score 0):

```
function example_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
}
```

Use this function to validate your data when submitting a form

Comment: As I said to Clive; My problem is that it makes sense for the error to be triggered in the submit handler. I have an API call that happens in the submit handler, if the API call fails, or returns an error, then I want to be able to set an error on the form and stay at the current step. I don't want to move the API call to a validation handler, because if successful the API call is a write action, so belongs at the submit stage. Also keeping it in the submit means other validators can prevent the API call from happening (eg honeypot).

Comment: @Simon unfortunately you're going to have to work around Drupal then (maybe patch the form submission process), as the form workflow isn't set up to handle such edge cases

Comment: Then you need to rebuild the current form in submit function. Then only you can use that form state again.

Comment: Take a look at the more advanced examples in the Form Example in the http://drupal.org/project/examples.

Comment: As you can see in my example, I am rebuilding the form,  but using form_set_error in the submit handler breaks this.

Answer (score 0):

form set error will clear your input, so do not use that function here. Instead, use the drupal_set_message. It is not perfect, but it will work.